# How do I use a constant argument in a function and not have to pass it from other functions when called

Tags: php, function, arguments

I have a function that has 3 arguments, one is always the same, ie a database connection.

```
function threeArgs($one,$two,$dbh){
       // some code here
}
```

This is the constant argument I want to pass.

```
$dbh = new PDO(..............);
```

I am trying to call threeArgs() function from another function but I only want to pass 2 arguments instead of 3 eg:

```
threeArgs($one,$two);
```

I can tell that this must be simple or im doing it completely wrong, but Im not sure what terminology I need to be searching for.

**UPDATE**

I have put the db connection inside a function and then called it from within the threeArgs() function. eg;

```
function dbconnection(){
     $dbh = //connect to dataase
    return $dbh;
 }
```

This is what I added in threeArgs().

```
function threeArgs($one, $two){
    dbconnection();
}
```

Is there a better way to do this?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: if $dbh is always constant then why would you pass it? Why dont you keep it in function?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Store it in [a `global` variable](http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.scope.php#example-99):

```
$dbh = new POD();

function threeArgs ( $one, $two ) {
     global $dbh;
     // use  $dbh here...
}
```

---

If you don't like the use of `global` variables, you can use [a `static` one](http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.scope.php#example-103) instead:

```
function threeArgs ( $one, $two ) {
     static $dbh = NULL;
     if ( ! $dbh ) $dbh = new POD();
     // use  $dbh here...
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the swift response @josephsilber, I would like to have $dbh always passed to the function.  Something like: `function threeArgs($one, $two, $dbh = $dbh){};` without having to do it within the function.

Comment: @user1441620 - I misread your question. I updated my answer to reflect that.

Comment: Thanks Joseph..im not 100% sure this is what Im looking for, I have placed the dbconnection in a function and called it from within the `threeArgs()`.